# jquery: Paste a set of elements over another set of elements / merging elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 sets of elements:

```
<div class='container container1'>
    <div class='colors'>
        <div class='blue'></div>
        <div class='red'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='drinks'>
        <div class='soda'>coke</div>
        <div class='juice'></div>
    </div>
</div>    

<div class='container container2'>
    <div class='cars'>
        <div class='sedans'></div>
        <div class='vans'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='drinks'>
        <div class='soda'>mountain dew</div>
        <div class='coffee'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to paste container1 over container2 such that any replacements are over written and any uniques to each container are put left alone and put together.

The result should be:

```
<div class='container container-result'>
    <div class='colors'>
        <div class='blue'></div>
        <div class='red'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='cars'>
        <div class='sedans'></div>
        <div class='vans'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='drinks'>
        <div class='soda'>coke</div>
        <div class='juice'></div>
        <div class='coffee'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The elements can have any arbitrary hierarchy / depth. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you summing soda 0 and soda 1 when they are merged? What if same-class divs to be merged contain non-numeric strings that differ?

Comment: @Ken Redler sorry not a sum, it's a replacement. The first should overwrite the second, I edited the example to be non-numeric. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is tagged jQuery here's a slightly shorter answer using that library:

```
function copy(from, to) {
    from.children().each(function() {
      var match = to.children("." + this.className.split(' ').join('.'));
        if(match.length) {
            if(match.children().length == 0) {
                match.replaceWith(this);
            } else {
                copy($(this), match);
            }
        } else {
            to.append(this);
        }
    }).end().remove();
    from.remove();
}
```

Then you'd just call it like this:

```
copy($(".container1"), $(".container2"));
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BMUPu/), the result is:

```
<div class="container container2">
  <div class="cars">
    <div class="sedans"></div>
    <div class="vans"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="drinks">
    <div class="soda">coke</div>
    <div class="coffee"></div>
    <div class="juice"></div></div>
  <div class="colors">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the class name is still `container2` if you want to replace that just add this  to switch the class after the `copy()` call:

```
$(".container2").toggleClass("container2 container-result");
```

The match is based on all classes the element contains, so if an element has `class="car blue"` and there's a corresponding `class="blue car"` it'll choose that one to overwrite.

This isn't the most efficient route since you're firing up the selector engine on the children each iteration, but unless you're doing *lots* of elements, it should be pretty quick.

Comment: To make this a bit more jQuery-ish, this can be rewritten as a jquery plugin as I have done here: http://jsfiddle.net/bBrYM/

Answer (score 0):

With regard to unique merging I can't help you there, but if your app by any chance happens to be in PHP then you can use php's [array_merge](http://www.php.net/array_merge) function to merge them before outputting the HTML.

[ReplaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) is a nice jquery function to replace aka "paste" over, it may will help you with half of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do what you wanted:

```
  <div class='container container1'>
      <div class='colors'>
          <div class='blue'></div>
          <div class='red'></div>
      </div>
      <div class='drinks'>
          <div class='soda'>coke</div>
          <div class='juice'></div>
      </div>
  </div>    

  <div class='container container2'>
      <div class='cars'>
          <div class='sedans'></div>
          <div class='vans'></div>
      </div>
      <div class='drinks'>
          <div class='soda'>mountain dew</div>
          <div class='coffee'></div>
      </div>
  </div>        

  <div class='container container-result'>
  </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function getContainerArray(containers, level) {
      level = level || 0;
      var result = [];
      for (var i=0; i<containers.length; ++i) {
        var el = containers.eq(i);
        var obj = { "class": el.attr("class") };
        if (level == 0) {
          obj.items = getContainerArray(el.children("div"), 1);
        } else {
          obj.text = el.text();
        }
        result.push(obj);
      }
      return result;
    }

    function mergeContainers(containerArray) {
      var result = [];

      function indexOfClass(name) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
          if (result[i]["class"] == name) {
            return i;
          }
        }
        return -1;
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < containerArray.length; ++i) {
        var obj = containerArray[i];
        var name = obj["class"];
        var index = indexOfClass(name);
        if (index < 0) {
          result.push(obj);
        } else if (obj.items != null) {
          result[index].items = mergeContainers(new Array().concat(result[index].items, obj.items));
        }
      }

      return result;
    }

    function getHtml(objArray) {
      var result = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; ++i) {
        var obj = objArray[i];
        result.push("<div class=\"", obj["class"], "\">");
        if (obj.text != null && obj.text != "") {
          result.push(obj.text);
        }
        if (obj.items != null) {
          result.push(getHtml(obj.items));
        }
        result.push("</div>");
      }
      return result.join("");
    }

    var html = getHtml(mergeContainers(getContainerArray($("div.container1>div,div.container2>div"))));
    $("div.container-result").append(html);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer:

1. Does exactly what you asked for.
2. Handles repeated mergings, if div class `container-result` already exists.
3. Merges any number of container divs.
4. Uses jQuery and is more efficient than some other solutions.

[**See it in action at jsfiddle.net.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nRGds/)

```
/*--- Get all "container" divs but exclude any "container-result" divs.
*/
var zContainers = $("div.container").not ("div.container-result");
if (zContainers  &&  zContainers.length)
{
    //--- Get or create the results div.
    var zResultDiv  = $("div.container-result");
    if (!zResultDiv  ||  !zResultDiv.length)
    {
        zResultDiv  = zContainers.parent ().append ("<div class='container container-result'></div>");
        zResultDiv  = $("div.container-result");
    }

    //--- Move the container's contents to the master container, preserving order.
    zContainers.each (function () {$(this).children ().appendTo (zResultDiv);} )

    //--- Kill the old container(s).
    zContainers.remove ();

    RecursivelyMergeDivsByClass (zResultDiv);
}

function RecursivelyMergeDivsByClass (jNode)
{
    /*--- Get a list of the direct-child div's class names.
        Sort and winny out a list of duplicates.
    */
    var zDirectChildDivs    = jNode.find ("> div");
    var aClassList          = zDirectChildDivs.map (function () {return this.className;} ).get ();
    aClassList.sort ().unshift (0);

    for (var J = aClassList.length-1;  J > 0;  J--)
        if (aClassList[J] != aClassList[J-1])   aClassList.splice (J, 1); // Delete items without duplicates.

    aClassList.splice (0, 1);

    /*--- For any duplicates, copy the contents into the first instance, preserving order.
        For exact duplicate nodes, the first (oldest) version is kept and the remaining are discarded.
    */
    for (var J = aClassList.length-1;  J >= 0;  J--)
    {
        var zDupClasses     = zDirectChildDivs.filter ("." + aClassList[J]);

        var zFirstDiv       = zDupClasses.first ();
        zDupClasses         = zDupClasses.not (zFirstDiv);

        zDupClasses.each (function () {$(this).children ().appendTo (zFirstDiv);} )
        zDupClasses.remove ();

        RecursivelyMergeDivsByClass (zFirstDiv)
    }
}
```